# Quick action custom icon on mobile not showing up

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, salesforce-mobile-app

How do I change the quick action icon on mobile?  I created my quick action and gave it a custom icon:

[image: quick action]

However, on mobile, I see no icon.

[image]

I've tried clearing cache as well as completely uninstalling/re-installing the app.

FYI - this is on the new mobile app that will be required for use in the Spring '20 release.

Comment: Follow-up question:  How do I change the background color of the icon?  Is that possible?

Comment: I’m getting this issue too now with Spring 20, you can’t change the colour of quick action there is an idea that hasn’t been done https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000PSNvAAO